# Flink reading sorted events but sorting is not maintained after partitioning

Tags: apache-flink, spark-streaming, flink-streaming, streaming-analytics

Using Flink `RichSourceFunction` I am reading a file which has events in sorted order based on timestamp field. The file is very large in size, 500GB. I am reading this file sequentially using only one split (`TimeStampedFileSplit`) for the whole file and partition count a 1. I am not using any watermarks or windowing for now. Then after reading this file I am performing a KeyBy operation on a different field and distributing the data across multiple partitions. So after distributing the data I notice that in some partitions the events are not sorted by timestamp. Why this can happen and how to make sure the events are always sorted ? Is there any theoretical explanation or proof for this ?